# ERROR: connection with gpfdist failed ; error code = 4 (Interrupted system call);

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, external-tables

Recently we did upgrade from GPDB 4.3 to GPDB 6.x, now I'm testing the new version , I got the error below when I'm reading from external table, I'm stuck and I can't find out a solution:

ERROR:  connection with gpfdist failed for "gpfdist://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090//REFILL/*.gz", effective url: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090//REFILL/*.gz": error code = 4 (Interrupted system call);  (seg0 slice1 xxx.xx.xx.x:6000 pid=752074)
SQL state: 08006

Answer (score 0):

It seems with the new upgrade the following settings might have changed.

1. GPFdist path.
2. Check the port on which gpfdist is running.

Comment: hi waqar-shahbaz, gpfdist process is well runnig with the used port, and for gpfdist PAth, I used the commande Source complete_path/greenplum_loaders_path.sh

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not specified file name correctly. You just specified .gz

Comment: Hi @Anikumar, I have just deleted the file name In the error message, in my external table the file name was mentioned correctly. Thanks for your remark.